# SQL Query Left Join - Second Table Column Joined Conditionally

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables

First table is called Donors like so

`+----------------+------------------------+--------+
|    Donor_ID    | Address_Validated_Date | Source |
+----------------+------------------------+--------+
| Character Data | 01JUN2016              | Web    |
+----------------+------------------------+--------+`

I have a second table that has donations

`+---------------+----------------+
| Donation_Date |    Donor_ID    |
+---------------+----------------+
| 01MAY2015     | Character data |
+---------------+----------------+`

Donation_Date can have values 0 meaning no donation or several dates reflecting donation dates like so

`+---------------+----------+
| Donation_Date | Donor_ID |
+---------------+----------+
| 01MAY2015     |        1 |
| 02MAY2015     |        1 |
| 0             |        2 |
+---------------+----------+`

What I need is a table that lists Donor_ID, Address_Validated_Date, Source with the first Donation_Date (eg. for 01MAY2015 for Donor_ID 1) or 0 if no donation.

Each Donor_ID should appear once - there should be one record for each Donor_ID. The added complication is that it should be for the last 2 months so Address_Validated_Date should start at 01APR2019.

Then I need another column created to show the difference in days between Donation_Date and Address_Validated_Date. The final output should be as so

`+----------+------------------------+--------+---------------+------------+
| Donor_ID | Address_Validated_Date | Source | Donation_Date | Days_After |
+----------+------------------------+--------+---------------+------------+`

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: Not much. I'm not sure how to approach since I can't test along the way - db is too huge to split it up and test as I go.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT D.Donor_ID
    ,D.Address_Validated_Date
    ,D.Source
    ,CASE 
        WHEN DS.Donation_Date IS NULL
            OR DATE (DS.Donation_Date) = '18000101'
            THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), DS.Donation_Date)
        ELSE 0
        END AS Donation_Date
    ,DS.Days_After
FROM Donors D
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Donar_ID
        ,MIN(Donation_Date) AS Donation_Date
    FROM donations
    GROUP BY Donar_ID
    ) DS
    ON D.Donor_ID = DS.Donor_ID
WHERE DATE(D.Address_Validated_Date)>='20190401'
```

Comment: Thanks, this works as I originally presented but I forgot an important detail. The added complication is that it should be for the last 2 months so Address_Validated_Date should start at 01APR2019. Please see original post for more information.

Comment: Added Date filter criteria!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use DATEDIFF function as follow

DATEDIFF(interval,STARTING_DATE,ENDING_DATE)

Your query will be as follow

```
SELECT DM.Donor_ID,DM.Address_Validated_Date,DM.Source,
D.Donation_Date,DATEDIFF(DAY,DM.Address_Validated_Date,D.Donation_Date) asDays_After  
FROM Donor D
LEFT JOIN DonorMaster DM on DM.Donor_ID=D.Donor_ID
```